# Unlock Surprise Mode?

Tags: luigis-mansion-dark-moon

While I was playing in the ScareScraper, I noticed someone's room had Surprise Mode. I don't have it as an option, but can someone tell me how I can unlock it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To unlock surprise mode you have win one of each type of ScareScraper (Polterpup, Rush and Hunter) on any floors on any difficulty.

From the [wiki](http://www.mariowiki.com/ScareScraper#Surprise_Mode).

> It is unlocked by completing the other three modes on any difficulty/floor amount at least once.

Comment: I need more detail, what do you mean by finishing the modes? Do you mean do I have to finish each mode on every difficulty?

Comment: Finish one of each mode on any difficulty

Comment: I have, but it has not shown up? Maybe a link to where you got the answer or a screenshot of it would help.

Comment: Read [here](http://www.mariowiki.com/ScareScraper#Surprise_Mode), you then have to click create a ScareScaraper.

Answer (score 2):

What you need to do is complete Hunter, Polterpup and Rush mode at least once on any difficulty. I would recommend that you play each mode on the easiest difficulty to unlock Surprise Mode much faster.

I hope this helped!